# Find minimum cost to convert to palindrome

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have been stuck in this problem for a long time and am unable to find any efficient solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Problem:

Given a string with lowercase characters we need to find the minimum cost to convert it into a palindrome. We can insert new characters and delete existing characters. Each character has a cost associated with it for insertion and deletion.

Cost is 'a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3,....., 'z' = 26

e.g. 'abc' -> 'c' with cost 3

I am only able to think of a approach which involves going through all the susbsequences which has an exponential time complexity.
Is there any way I can optimize it?

Comment: The cost of replacing with z is 26 and replacing with a is one?! Isn't the cost of all replacements, insertion, and deletions the same? Then what is the cost of deletion and insertion?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I understood the problem wrongly. I have updated the question.

Comment: Then, is it a homework question?

Comment: No, I got this problem asked in an interview. Still figuring out the efficient solution.

Comment: Must the resulting palindrome have the same length as the original string? If not, you could just delete all but the most expensive character. `abc` → `c` (cost 3)

Comment: There is no such restriction on length. Yes you could delete but it won't give the correct result in all the cases. Like 'abcb' -> 'abcba' cost 1.  Also thanks for pointing out the mistake in my example. I have updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine a recursive solution where you solve the problem of making the first and last character the same, and then solve the problem for the remaining characters (excluding the first and last character).

If the first and last character of the string are already the same, it makes no sense to consider inserting a character at the very beginning or end of the string, nor to delete either the first or last character. That would only add to the cost.

When different, there are several options to get a first character that is the same as the last one:

1. insert a character at the very beginning: the same character that is currently the last character of the string. The cost of this character should be added to the cost that recursion will give for the original string without its last character.
2. insert a character at the very end: the same character that is currently the first character of the string. The cost of this character should be added to the cost that recursion will give for the original string without its first character.
3. delete the character at the very end: This may not immediately make the first and last character equal, as more characters might need to be deleted/inserted. But that choice would be the job for the recursive call. The cost of this character should be added to the cost that recursion will give for the remaining string.
4. delete the character at the very beginning (same reasoning as option 3): The cost of this character should be added to the cost that recursion will give for the remaining string.

Observe that the recursive call made in option 1 and 3 is the same, and also the cost that is added is exactly the same. A similar observation holds when comparing option 2 and 4. For example, when the input is "abcb", we can see that adding "a" at the end, or deleting "a" from the beginning, both yield a palindrome at the same cost. So actually we only need to consider 2 of these 4 options.

After making the recursive calls for these two options, the only thing that remains is to pick the cheapest of the two.

The recursion stops when only 1 character (or none) is left over: for that case the cost is 0 since that string is a palindrome. that (zero) cost and even the corresponding palindrome could be returned back to the caller.

Some optimisation is possible by memoization: keep track of results per visited range.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, which has an interactive input where you can see the corresponding calculated cost and palindrome in real time:

```js
function toPalindrome(s, charCost) {
    let visited = [];
    function recur(i, j) {
        let key = i * s.length + j;
        if (visited[key]) return visited[key];  // use memoization
        let cost = 0, palindrome;
        if (i >= j) { // Base case
            palindrome = i > j ? "" : s[i];
        } else if (s[i] === s[j]) {
            // If outermost two characters are equal: take them; no extra cost
            ({ cost, palindrome } = recur(i+1, j-1));
            palindrome = s[i] + palindrome + s[i];
        } else { // Otherwise consider deleting either first or last char
            ({ cost, palindrome } = recur(i, j-1));
            cost += charCost[s[j]];
            let { cost: cost2, palindrome: palindrome2 } = recur(i+1, j);
            cost2 += charCost[s[i]];
            if (cost2 < cost) { // Take best of the two searched branches
                cost = cost2;
                palindrome = palindrome2;
            }
        }
        // Return two informations: cost and palindrome.
        return visited[key] = { cost, palindrome };
    }
    return recur(0, s.length-1);
}

const charCost = [...Array(26).keys()].reduce((acc, i) => 
    (acc[String.fromCharCode(i+97)] = i+1, acc), {});
// I/O handling
(document.oninput = () =>
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(toPalindrome(input.value, charCost), null, 2)
)();
```

```html
Input: <input id="input" value="antenna"><br>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

### Returning all palindromes

As the deletion of a character at one end comes at the same cost as adding that character at the opposite end, there can be several palindromes that can be created at the same minimal cost.

Here is a version of the code that collects all those palindromes instead of just one. Obviously, this uses some extra execution time and space:

```js
function toPalindrome(s, charCost) {
    let visited = [];
    function recur(i, j) {
        let key = i * s.length + j;
        if (visited[key]) return visited[key];  // use memoization
        let cost = 0, palindromes;
        if (i >= j) { // Base case
            palindromes = [i > j ? "" : s[i]];
        } else if (s[i] === s[j]) {
            // If outermost two characters are equal: take them; no extra cost
            ({ cost, palindromes } = recur(i+1, j-1));
            palindromes = palindromes.map(pal => s[i] + pal + s[i]);
        } else { // Otherwise consider deleting either first or last char
            ({ cost, palindromes } = recur(i, j-1));
            // add an alternative for every palindrome: using an insertion instead of deletion
            //    at the opposite end of the string
            palindromes = [...palindromes, ...palindromes.map(pal => s[j] + pal + s[j])];
            cost += charCost[s[j]];
            let { cost: cost2, palindromes: palindromes2 } = recur(i+1, j);
            cost2 += charCost[s[i]];
            if (cost2 <= cost) { // Take best of the two searched branches
                if (cost2 < cost) {
                    palindromes = [];
                }
                palindromes = [...palindromes, ...palindromes2, ...palindromes2.map(pal => s[i] + pal + s[i])];
                cost = cost2;
            } 
        }
        // Return two informations: cost and palindrome.
        return visited[key] = { cost, palindromes };
    }
    let result = recur(0, s.length-1);
    result.palindromes = [...new Set(result.palindromes)]; // make unique
    return result;
}

const charCost = [...Array(26).keys()].reduce((acc, i) => 
    (acc[String.fromCharCode(i+97)] = i+1, acc), {});
// I/O handling
(document.oninput = () =>
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(toPalindrome(input.value, charCost), null, 2)
)();
```

```html
Input: <input id="input" value="antenna"><br>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice analysis.  I'm wondering if there would be a straightforward change that captured *all* palindromes of the lowest cost.  So `'abcde' => {cost: 10, palindromes: ['e', 'abcdedcba']}`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, Yes, that would be possible. If the OP shows interest in that I will add it.

Comment: Yes, looking at the code more closely, it's clear enough how to do it.  I wish I hadn't seen your answer before I tried the problem myself.  It seems an interesting challenge, but now I can't imagine any other way of looking at it!  Well done!

Comment: @trincot please add it. It is a good extension to the problem.

Comment: Suppose input is azzzaa, it totally makes sense to remove the last a or insert another a at the start. (in regard to this claim: "If the first and last character of the string are already the same, it makes no sense to consider inserting a character at the very beginning or end of the string, nor to delete either the first or last character.")

Comment: Yes, but the decision to add or remove an "a" can be made one level deeper in the recursion, when the string has become "zzza". So, it is OK to *not* consider that option when the string is still "azzzaa". It just avoids duplication of work.

Comment: Ok, that argument is actually correct, for this case, I don't know if it is possible to construct any other case. I guess there is no other edge case.

Comment: @AnchitJain, as requested, I added a version that returns all palindromes that come at the same, minimal cost.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
enum Action { Initial, Unchanged, Insert, Delete }

int defaultEditCost(char ch) => char.ToLower(ch) - 'a' + 1;

int editDistancePalindrime(string str, Func<char, int> costFn)
{
    // Calculate the levenshtein distance table between `str` and its reverse.
    // str[i-1] is the normal string, and str[n-j] is the reverse.
    int n = str.Length;
    var table = new (Action action, int totalCost, int actionCost)[n + 1, n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) table[i, j] = (Action.Initial, 0, 0);
            else if (i == 0)
            {
                var insertCost = costFn(str[n - j]);
                var insertTotalCost = table[i, j - 1].totalCost + insertCost;
                table[i, j] = (Action.Insert, insertTotalCost, insertCost);
            }
            else if (j == 0)
            {
                var deleteCost = costFn(str[i - 1]);
                var deleteTotalCost = table[i - 1, j].totalCost + deleteCost;
                table[i, j] = (Action.Delete, deleteTotalCost, deleteCost);
            }
            else if (str[i - 1] == str[n - j])
            {
                table[i, j] = (Action.Unchanged, table[i - 1, j - 1].totalCost, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                var insertCost = costFn(str[n - j]);
                var deleteCost = costFn(str[i - 1]);
                var insertTotalCost = table[i, j - 1].totalCost + insertCost;
                var deleteTotalCost = table[i - 1, j].totalCost + deleteCost;
                if (insertTotalCost <= deleteTotalCost)
                {
                    table[i, j] = (Action.Insert, insertTotalCost, insertCost);
                }
                else
                {
                    table[i, j] = (Action.Delete, deleteTotalCost, deleteCost);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // The cost is the sum of actionCost for all inserts or all deletes.
    // (Both have the same value, because of symmetry.)
    int palindromeCost = 0;
    for (int i = n, j = n; i > 0 || j > 0;)
    {
        var (action, totalCost, actionCost) = table[i, j];
        switch (action)
        {
            case Action.Insert:
                palindromeCost += actionCost;
                j--;
                break;
            case Action.Delete:
                i--;
                break;
            case Action.Unchanged:
                i--;
                j--;
                break;
        }
    }
    return palindromeCost;
}
```

```cs
void Main()
{
    editDistancePalindrime("abc", defaultEditCost).Dump();
    // 'abc' -> 'c' or 'abcba' (cost 3)

    editDistancePalindrime("anchitjain", defaultEditCost).Dump();
    // 'anchitjain' -> 'nitin' or 'anchiajtjaihcna' (cost 23)
}
```

Comment: I compared the output of your solution with mine over thousands of random input, and they return the same. Nice solution (+1)